# MongoDB Illegal character driving me nuts

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB is giving me [js] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):2:5

when writing

```
> db.createUser({
... user:¨brad¨,
... pwd:¨1234¨,
... roles: [ ¨readWrite¨, ¨dbAdmin¨]
... });
```

I know it has something to do with the colon, but anything seems to fix it.

I run it on mac if it gives any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with the weird quote character, but just use the standard quote character (`"` instead of `¨`):

```
> db.createUser({
... user:"brad",
... pwd:"1234",
... roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin"]
... });
```

It seems like the JS engine doesn't recognize U+0308 as a quote character.

Edit: After looking it up, it's not a quote - it's two dots intended to be horizontally aligned over other characters.

Comment: Wow, it worked indeed, but I don't really understand what did you change or if you know how to change it using the mac's keyboard.

Comment: @IsmaelMarcos Try this guide, your keyboard may be in the preset of a different language: https://thetypingcat.com/howto/change-your-keyboard-layout-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, tried different tricks and finally was able to fix it. Don't forget to try tilt(`) instead of double quotes(") or single quotes(') in case none of this worked for you. Happy coding!!!!